# Add Styling to the Search/filters component (Bootstrap) ASP.NET core

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core, razor, bootstrap-4

I am trying to style and put multiple search filters on the page in a line so the User Experience is much better but I am kind of stuck with how to style this search component

```
<section class="search-sec">
 <div class="container">
    <form asp-action="Index" method="get">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-12 p-0">
                        <input class="" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="@ViewData["name"]" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 p-0">
                            <label for="age" class="">Age</label>
                            <select class="" name="age">
                                ........
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0">
                        <label for="minAge">Age range between</label>
                        <select name="minAge">
                         ......
                        </select>
                        and
                        <select name="maxAge">
                           ......
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0">
                        <label for="sex">Sex</label>
                        <select name="sex">
                            .....
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0">
                        <label for="stockNumber">Find by Stock Number</label>
                        <input type="text" name="stockNumber" value="@ViewData["stockNumber"]" 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0">
                        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" /> |
                        <a class="btn btn-link" asp-action="Index">Clear</a>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       </form>
     </div>
    </section>
```

The issue even after changing the sizes and all it looks like below

[image]

I tried looking for bootstrapping example and nothing helped. Can anyone please suggest how can I make this search functionality look better. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi @user4912134, the width of the browser is limited. I have tested your code and try to put them in a line, but your view contains several label like `Age range between`, it will occupy the space. Also, your input is a bit large, also makes impossible in a line. If you allow reduce some label text and change the input width, I think I can share you the demo. If not, it cannot be in a line.

Comment: @Rena If you can share a demo That will be great. Thanks

Comment: Hi @user4912134, updated an answer. If any problems, please follow up to let me know.

Comment: @Rena I was asked to add couple of new filter to the search, so as you suggested I tried to put each row two components and changed the size of the `col-lg-* ` for each div class but not able to align them can you please help with this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69944592/putting-space-between-my-div-classes-and-align-them`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid system contains 12 columns. If you want to put them in one line, the `*` in `col-lg-*` should sum within 12. Then you also need to adjust the letter to avoid the letter length over the div width.

Here is a whole working demo:

```
<section class="search-sec">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <form asp-action="Index" method="get">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-12 p-0">
                            <input class="" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="@ViewData["name"]" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12">
                            <label for="age" class="">Age</label>
                            <select class="" name="age">
                                <option>- Any -</option>
                                <option>aaa</option>
                                <option>bbb</option>
                                <option>ccc</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0">
                            <label for="minAge">Age range from</label>
                            <select name="minAge">
                                <option>- Start -</option>
                                <option>1</option>
                                <option>2</option>
                            </select>
                            to
                            <select name="maxAge">
                                <option>- End -</option>
                                <option>14</option>
                                <option>15</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                            <label for="sex">Sex</label>
                            <select name="sex">
                                <option>- Either -</option>
                                <option>male</option>
                                <option>female</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0">
                            <label for="stockNumber">Stock No.</label>
                        </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0">
                                <input type="text" name="stockNumber" value="aaa" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0">
                                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" /> |
                                <a class="btn btn-link" asp-action="Index">Clear</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
@section Scripts
{
<style>
    input[type="text"] {
        width: 100%;   //fit the div width
    }
    select {
        width: 65px;
    }
</style>
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you ton !!! is there a way we can add a border around this

Comment: Does the border surround with the whole line?