# Putting space between my div classes and align them

Tags: html, css, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have few search filters on my page and a data card ASP.Net Core application. I am trying to align them on the page so it looks better. Currently it looks like below

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-3">
         <div class="card  border-info mb-3" style="max-width: 12rem;">
            <div class="card-header text-center"><b>Current Shipping Address</b></div>
            <div class="card-body text-info" style="font-size: 14px;">
                <b><h7 class="card-title">Location</h7></b>
                <p class="card-text">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CustomerData.Location)
                    <br />@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CustomerData.Address1)
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-9">
        <section class="search-sec">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <form asp-action="Index" method="get">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-2 col-sm-12 p-0">
                                    <label for="name" class="">Strain Name</label>
                                    <input class="" type="text" name="name" value="@ViewData["name"]" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-2 col-sm-12 p-0">
                                    <label for="genotype" class="">Genotype</label>
                                    <input class="" type="text" name="genotype" value="@ViewData["genotype"]" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-12 p-0">
                                    <label for="age" class="">Age</label>
                                    <select class="" name="age">
                                      ......
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-2 col-sm-12 p-0">
                                    <label for="minAge">Age range between</label>
                                    <select name="minAge">
                                     .......
                                    </select>
                                    and
                                    <select name="maxAge">
                                       ........
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-12 p-0">
                                    <label for="sex">Sex</label>
                                    <select name="sex">
                                        ......
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-12 p-0">
                                    <div class="form-group form-actions col-md-10 no-color">
                                        <label for="stockNumber">Find by Stock Number</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="stockNumber" value="@ViewData["stockNumber"]" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-12 p-0">
                                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" /> |
                                <a class="btn btn-link" asp-action="Index">Return to Original List</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
       </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

I am trying put the data card in the left and align the search filters in the right 2 in a row and show them in 3 rows.
I tried changing the sizes of the `col-lg-*` in each row on the filters but still cannot align them like what I am trying any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-3">
         <div class="card  border-info mb-3" style="max-width: 12rem;">
            <div class="card-header text-center"><b>Current Shipping Address</b></div>
            <div class="card-body text-info" style="font-size: 14px;">
                <b><h7 class="card-title">Location</h7></b>
                <p class="card-text">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CustomerData.Location)
                    <br />@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CustomerData.Address1)
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-9">
        <section class="search-sec">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <form asp-action="Index" method="get">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-2 form-check-inline mr-0">
                                    <label for="name" class="col-auto">Strain Name</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" value="@ViewData["name"]" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-2  form-check-inline mr-0">
                                    <label for="genotype" class="col-auto">Genotype</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="genotype" value="@ViewData["genotype"]" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-12 form-check-inline m-0">
                                    <label for="age" class="col-auto" >Age</label>
                                    <select class="form-control px-1" name="age">
                                     <option>-Any-</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-2 col-sm-12 form-check-inline m-0 justify-content-between">
                                    <label class="col-auto" for="minAge">Age range between</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" name="minAge">
                                      <option>-Start-</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <label class="col-auto" for="minAge">and</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" name="maxAge">
                                       <option>-End-</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 form-check-inline m-0">
                                    <label class="col-auto" for="sex">Sex</label>
                                    <select class="form-control px-1" name="sex">
                                        <option>-Either-</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-2 col-sm-12 form-check-inline m-0">
                                        <label class="col-auto" for="stockNumber">Find by Stock Number</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="stockNumber" value="@ViewData["stockNumber"]" />
                                </div>
                              <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-2 col-sm-12 form-check-inline m-0">
                                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" /> |
                                <a class="btn btn-link" asp-action="Index">Return to Original List</a>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
       </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please show an example how it shows up in your screen

Comment: updated, Please check

Comment: have you tried offsetting your columns? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns

Comment: Thank you so much I have updated the question again . to show how it appears on my screen. Is there a way I can make the last row fixed

Comment: @Richie I have not tried it , this is my application with the ASP.NET framework and bootstraping

Comment: Read through the bootstrap documentation on the grid system, it should be fairly easy to achieve the exact layout that you want

Comment: please update the code as well , in my screen its working fine,

also mark this as answer if it works for you.

Comment: @Diwyansh It works fine now.. I missed some div tags.. Can you please let me know how to add the border for  this search component

Comment: you can use "border" class for border and give some padding for space between text and border

Comment: Should it be with the `<div class="container-fluid">` ?

Comment: <div class="col-auto border py-1">Search</div> you can py-2 or py-3 as per your choice

Comment: @Diwyansh Can you please take a look in to my question.. I see a space between the data card and the the Search filters. Is there a way to but these two side by side?

Comment: @Diwyansh If needed I can create a separate question

Comment: I think the reason is you using col-9 inside col-9 turn the second col-9 into col-12